# Conditions on convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Suppose non-negative sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies the following relation: $$a_{n+1} - 2a_n \leq b_n+c_n a_n + d_n a_n^{\frac{p-1}{p}},$$ where $b_n, c_n , d_n$ are the sequences converging to $0$ and $p > 1$ be any real number.

Now I am trying to prove the convegence of above sequence $\{a_n\}$. Does it converge towards $0$ or what condition should we apply on it so that this sequence converges towards $0$?

Any help thanks.

Comment: The relation leaves a lot of freedom for the sequence $\{a_n\}$. For instance, for any sequences $\{b_n\}$, $\{c_n\}$, and $\{d_n\}$ of non-negative numbers, any sequence  $\{a_n\}$ such that $1\le a_n\le 2$ for each $n$ satisfies the relation.